# Radio wave simulation tools

Tags: waves, simulations

I am looking for a free simulating tool for the propagation of waves given constraint. I am assuming a scenario with a source, a receiver, and some constraining reflecting\absorbing surfaces (metal surfaces or enclosures for radio waves for example). Given a signal emitted from the source, I want to simulate the signal received by the receiver. Which tools can I use?

Comment: You might look at EZNEC, which has a free version available. Depends on the specifics of the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a nice comparison of simulation software [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EM_simulation_software). For engineers, I recommend Comsol.